# my net/http post method give 100% cpu usage

Tags: go, post

I have a web server with net/http and julienschmidt/httprouter. I don't know why, but if I post a "big" data, like hundred of newline from `<textarea>`, my go server dies.

I already tried to use goroutine to make `for _, value := range target` exclude from main thread and try to increase ulimit, but it seems doesn't work
code:

```
func CreateRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(0)

    Title, Caption, Target := r.Form["title"], r.Form["caption"], r.Form["target"]

    if len(Title) > 0 && len(Caption) > 0 && len(Target) > 0 {

        CampaignId := helper.Md5Gen(time.Now().String())

        target := strings.Split(Target[0], "\n")

        for _, value := range target {

            value = strings.Replace(value, "\r", "", -1)

            if len(value) > 6 {
                data := structs.CampaignTarget{
                    CampaignId: CampaignId,
                    PhoneNumber: value,
                    IsExecuted: false,
                    ExecutedBy: "",
                    IsSuccess: false,
                    SendAt: int64(0),
                    Username: LoggedUsername(w, r),
                }
                database, err := helper.DataDatabase()
                if err == nil {
                    database.C("xxx").Insert(&data)
                }
            }
        }

        SavedFileName := ""

        file, handler, err := r.FormFile("media")

        if err == nil {

            path := "/xxx/path/" + LoggedUsername(w, r)

            err := os.MkdirAll(path, os.ModePerm)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, "Problem with folder creation", 500)
                return
            }

            defer file.Close()

            SavedFileName = fmt.Sprintf("%v-%v", helper.Md5Gen(time.Now().String()), handler.Filename)

            f, err := os.OpenFile(path+"/"+SavedFileName, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, "Failed to Write File", 500)
                return
            }
            defer f.Close()
            io.Copy(f, file)

        }

        data := structs.Campaign{
            ID: CampaignId,
            Title: Title[0],
            Caption: Caption[0],
            TotalTarget: len(target),
            Media: SavedFileName,
            Username: LoggedUsername(w, r),
            CreatedAt: time.Now().Unix(),
        }
        database, err := helper.DataDatabase()
        if err == nil {
            database.C("xx").Insert(&data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `LoggedUsername` talking to the db? If so, maybe call it just once, at the top, and not for every single line of the input. Same with inserting data, maybe first aggregate each CampaignTarget into a slice and then insert that slice, once, if your db supports it. Similarly `helper.DataDatabase()`...

Comment: i think the LoggedUsername is fine sir for receiving hundred of request at once, idk why maybe i forgot to close something

Comment: what does profiling tell you? https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: Please read up what r.ParseMultipartForm(0) does. Then think why you used 0. Then use something sensible.

Comment: What does "my go server dies" mean? The request times out? The server crashes/exits? If it crashes or exits, what is the output?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that splitting on newlines, where all of the contents of the string to split on is newlines is an expensive operation.

```golang
target := strings.Split(Target[0], "\n")
```

If you want to split newlines, consider using a `bufio.Scanner` instead

```golang
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader("foo\nbar\nbaz"))
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
```

[Runnable example](https://play.golang.org/p/gu77NYCwPkI)

This is because scanner advances to the next token when you call scan, whereas `strings.Split` processes the whole payload at once.